# Assign a textbox value to a decimal variable VB

Tags: vb.net, textbox, decimal

I am currently working in VB and am having a hard time with converting a input of a textbox to a decimal variable.

This is my On Click attempt which results in:

> Input string was not in a correct format

```vb
Dim totalSale As Decimal = Convert.ToDecimal(total_tb.Text)
```

Ideally I would like to assign the input of the textbox to `totalSale` AND keep any decimal value if any from the textbox.

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to convert text that doesn't represent a number into a number? That's not a problem. If your actual problem is validating the input then that's the problem you should describe.

Comment: Are you using the correct decimal dot for your current thread culture? `.` or `,`?

Comment: I'm no expert jmcilhinney so bare with me. How do you propose I validate it?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with thread culture to be honest. I've been using "." for other aspects of the code and its been fine.

Comment: Then consult [your OS settings](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-windows-regional-settings-to-modify-the-appearance-of-some-data-types-edf41006-f6e2-4360-bc1b-30e9e8a54989) to learn which character you should use. In the source code you use `.` because this is the source code.

Comment: I checked and the decimal related drop down boxes have the value of .

Comment: Any thousands separators? What kind of thing are you entering there?

Comment: What is the string that is in `total_tb.Text`?

Comment: For any thousands separators, Im not quite sure what you mean but the examples in the control panel show having commas to indicate a thousand like 1,000.

Comment: I am trying to enter an amount like 2 or 2.00 for example

Comment: Either would work. If it doesn't, your app culture is something different, or you are not entering it into the right textbox.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you use a `NumericUpDown` control instead; its Value is already a decimal, and it overcomes most of the shortcomings around bad user input associated with trying to use a Textbox to caputure numeric input

Answer (score 0):

If you must continue to use a `TextBox`, this will validate user input and provide you with a variable of type `Decimal`. `.TryParse` returns `True` or `False` and if `True` fills the second parameter, `totalSale`, with the converted string value.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim totalSale As Decimal
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(total_tb.Text, totalSale) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number.")
        Return
    End If
    'Code that works with totalSale
End Sub
```